# What causes an iOS webapp to freeze on the startup screen?

Tags: ios, html, splash-screen, freeze, iphone-standalone-web-app

I developed an HTML5 webapp, and so far my local server tests worked fine (running in the desktop browser, iOS Safari browser, and homescreen bookmark webapp). This also holds true for the offline use (with the cache.manifest file).

When I uploaded the files to my website, I tested to confirm it still works on the desktop (Chrome shows the Application Cache logs), also works in iOS Safari. Both online and offline.

## The Problem

When I bookmark the page from my website as a homescreen icon and try to launch it from there, the webapp freezes on the startup image.

What could be causing this particular issue?

### Checklist:

- HTML tag contains: `<html manifest="cache.manifest">`
- HTML does contain: `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`
- HTML does contain: `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">`
- Not sure this would matter but: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, minimal-ui, user-scalable=no">`
- The `apple-touch-startup-image` and `apple-touch-icon` link tags are appended dynamically to the `<head>` tag via Javascript.
- Only the necessary file-names in `cache.manifest` are included.
- The webhost supports the `manifest` mimeType (no need to change `.htaccess`).
- The website does use an `.htaccess` password authentication setting.

**NOTE: I will investigate whether or not my use of `apple-touch-startup-image` & `apple-touch-icon` dynamically appended with jQuery could be the issue here.**

Comment: Already a -1 vote with no explanation why... great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It dawned on me once I listed the **`.htaccess` password authentication** bit in the checklist above.

It seems iOS's chromeless browser cannot initiate a username & password prompt at startup.

Sure enough, allowing full access to the page resolved the issue for the homescreen app. To do so, I've included this in a separate `.htaccess` file in the same directory the webapp is placed in:

```
Satisfy Any
```

That's it!

Although I'm not very fond of this solution, then again I wouldn't want to enter a username & password everytime I launch the webapp.